# AngularJS, Async - ng-repeat not waiting for scope to be set

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I load up my index page, my ajax call works and the scope does get set. But it seems like ng-repeat is loading before the scope gets set with "products".

I feel like there should be a way to either

1. Load the page without having to wait for the scope to be set, but when it does get set - then re-run the loop "ng-repeat"
2. Wait for the AJAX Call to be done before initializing the loop ('ng-repeat')

Cheers!

products.controller.js

```
dvpModule.controller("ProductsController", function ($scope, productRepository) {
    productRepository.get().then(function(products) { 
    $scope.products = products; 
    });
});
```

products-repository.js

```
dvpModule.factory('productRepository', function($http, $q) {
return {
    get: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            params: { action: 'getAllProductUrls' },
        }).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="dvpModule">

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/scripts/dvp_module.js" /></script>
    <script src="js/scripts/products-controller.js" /></script>
    <script src="js/scripts/products-repository.js" /></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>DVP {{2 + 2}}</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ProductsController">
    <div>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
        <th>{{product.Category}}</th>
        <th>{{product.Features}}</th>
        <th>{{product.MODEL_SERIES}}</th>
    </tr>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't have to do any of above two, what angular does is , when you load something via `$http` it will execute `$scope.$apply()`. Which means re render your ng-repear if there are any changes in `$scope.products`

Comment: Then why does my ng-repeat not work? Because I see that the page is loading and 1-2 seconds later $http will return the data and Angular does not refresh...

Comment: The above should work. When your `$http` is complete and you run the callback to set `$scope.products = products`, it should notice that `$scope.products` has changed and rerun the `ng-repeat` for you. If it isn't, then something is not getting passed through

Comment: Can you put breakpoints and/or `console.log` inside your factory and callback in the controller to see what is getting passed through? Also, what is returned by the `$http.get()`?

Comment: did you find the solution am already struggling here

Comment: I believe defining my scope inside of the function initially was the issue...  I will define my objects now at the top of the controller before even setting them.
So I'll define the Products variable as an empty array then run a function to set it. OR have an ng-if="products.length > 0" before your ng-repeat if you don't want the repeater to run.